# recursive function multiply and sum

Tags: python, function, recursion

Hope to find some help here with a new excercise.

I luckily understand how to use recursive functions, but this one is killing me, im probably just thinking too much outside of the box.

We're given a string:

```
c = "3+4*5+6+1*3"
```

And now we have to code a function, which recursivly gives us the result of that calculation.

Now i know the recursive end should be the length of the string, which should be 1.

Our professor did give us another example which we should use for this function.

1. `int(number)`
2. `string.split(symbol, 1)`

we have following code given:

```
c = "3+4*5+6+1*3"
print(c)
print()

sub1, sub2 = c.split("+", 1)
print("Result with '+':")
print("sub1=" + sub1)
print("sub2=" + sub2)
print()

sub1, sub2 = c.split("*", 1)
print("Result with '*':")
print("sub1=" + sub1)
print("sub2=" + sub2)
print()
```

My thoughts were to split the strings to a minimum, so i can turn them into integers and than sum them together. But im absolutly lost there how the code should look like, im a real beginner so im really sorry. I dont even know it the beginning i was thinking of is right. Still hoping, someone can help!
what i had:

```
def calc(string):
   if len(string) == 1:
      return string
```

Thanks for all of you!

Greets
Chrissi

Comment: Are you supposed to implement operator precedence, so that `*` binds more tightly than `+`? Or should you just calculate sequentially?

Comment: need more info. what are the operators to expect? precedence matters? how are you expected to retrieve the operators? can you just assume every other char is an operator?

Comment: you said you were thinking outside the box? tell us what you thought?

Comment: the result of the calculation for 3+4*5+6+1*3 should be 32

Comment: If ALL you have to support is + and *, then this is pretty easy.  Just split on "+", then if any of the pieces contains a "*", call another function to split on "*" and do the computation.  This falls apart if you have to handle parentheses, but for now it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I created a function that solves equations like these. However, the only characters possible are numbers, and operators add (+) and mult (*). If you try to use any other characters such as spaces, there's going to be errors.

```
# Solves a mathematical equation containing digits [0-9], and operators
# such as add + or multiply *
def solve(equation, operators, oindex=0):
    # If an operator is available, use the operator
    if (oindex < len(operators)):

        # Get the current operator and pair: a op b
        op = operators[oindex]
        pair = equation.split(op, 1)
        
        # If the pair is a pair (has 2 elements)
        if (len(pair) == 2):
            # Solve left side
            a = solve(pair[0], operators)

            # Solve right side
            b = solve(pair[1], operators)

            # If current operator is multiply: multiply a and b
            if (op == '*'):
                print(a, '*', b, '=', a*b)
                return a * b

            # If current operator is add: add a and b
            elif (op == '+'):
                print(a, '+', b, '=', a+b)
                return a + b

        # If it's not a pair, try using another operator
        else:
            return solve(equation, operators, oindex+1)

    else:
        # If no operators are available, then equation is
        # just a number.
        return int(equation)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    equation = "3+4*5+6+1*3"
    
    # If mult (*) takes precedence, operator order is "+*"
    # > 3+4*5+6+1*3 = ((3)+((4*5)+((6)+(1*3))))
    # = ((3)+((20)+((6)+(3))))
    # = ((3)+(20+(9)))
    # = ((3)+(29))
    # = (32)
    print("MULT, then ADD -> ",equation + " = ", solve(equation, "+*"))

    # If add (+) takes precedence, operator order is "*+"
    # > 3+4*5+6+1*3 = ((3+4)*(((5)+(6+1))*(3)))
    # = ((7)*((5+7)*(3)))
    # = ((7)*(12*3))
    # = (7*36)
    # = (252)
    print("ADD, then MULT -> ",equation + " = ", solve(equation, "*+"))
```

To set the operators, you can use the paramter `operators`, which is a string that takes all supported operators. In this case: `+*`.

The order of these characters matter, changing the precedence of each operator inside the equation.

Here's the output:

```
4 * 5 = 20
1 * 3 = 3
6 + 3 = 9
20 + 9 = 29
3 + 29 = 32
MULT, then ADD ->  3+4*5+6+1*3 =  32
3 + 4 = 7
6 + 1 = 7
5 + 7 = 12
12 * 3 = 36
7 * 36 = 252
ADD, then MULT ->  3+4*5+6+1*3 =  252
```